# add key pair value in array in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to make an key pair array in `foreach` loop in `php`. In my `foreach loop` i have city name and user name. I want to add all users for same city in array.

Ex `[{city=>'pune',users=>("a","b","c","d")},{'city=>nk',users=>("e","b","c","f")}]` or any other array format.

```
foreach ($studsInfo as $value) {
    $studId = "".$value['_id'];
    $indDetail = $industryM->getAllIndustries($studId);
    $indusArray['industry'] = iterator_to_array($indDetail);
    $city = $value['city'];
    $name = $value['firstname'];
}
```

How could I add all `name` in array for same `city`.

Thankx in advance, Any suggestion and editing are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the city as the key users from the city as value.

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($studsInfo as $value) {
    $studId = "".$value['_id'];
    $indDetail = $industryM->getAllIndustries($studId);
    $indusArray['industry'] = iterator_to_array($indDetail);
    //$city = $value['city'];
    //$name = $value['firstname'];
    $arr[$value['city'][] = $value['firstname'];
}
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = array('city' => $k, 'users' => $v);
}
```

Comment: Thnkx a lot, this really helps me.